# DooM P_BulletSlope function , how does it works

Tags: collision-detection, mathematics, 2.5d

I'm trying to understand how DOOM source code works, the problem is I don't understand a few things, why is it 16 * 64 * FRACUNIT ? , i don't get it.

```
static void P_BulletSlope(mobj_t *actor)
{
    if (usemouselook && !autoaim)
        bulletslope = PLAYERSLOPE(viewplayer);
    else
    {
        // killough 08/02/98: make autoaiming prefer enemies
        int mask = MF_FRIEND;

        do
        {
            angle_t an = actor->angle;

            // see which target is to be aimed at
            bulletslope = P_AimLineAttack(actor, an, 16 * 64 * FRACUNIT, mask);

            if (!linetarget)
            {
                bulletslope = P_AimLineAttack(actor, (an += (1 << 26)), 16 * 64 * FRACUNIT, mask);

                if (!linetarget)
                {
                    bulletslope = P_AimLineAttack(actor, an - (2 << 26), 16 * 64 * FRACUNIT, mask);

                    if (!linetarget && usemouselook)
                        bulletslope = PLAYERSLOPE(viewplayer);
                }
            }
        } while (mask && (mask = 0, !linetarget));  // killough 08/02/98
    }
}
```

another function (P_AimLineAttack) .

```
fixed_t P_AimLineAttack(mobj_t *t1, angle_t angle, fixed_t distance, int mask)
{
    fixed_t x2, y2;

    if (!t1)
        return 0;

    angle >>= ANGLETOFINESHIFT;
    shootthing = t1;

    x2 = t1->x + (distance >> FRACBITS) * finecosine[angle];
    y2 = t1->y + (distance >> FRACBITS) * finesine[angle];
    shootz = t1->z + (t1->height >> 1) + 8 * FRACUNIT;

    // can't shoot outside view angles
    topslope = (VANILLAHEIGHT / 2) * FRACUNIT / (VANILLAWIDTH / 2);
    bottomslope = -(VANILLAHEIGHT / 2) * FRACUNIT / (VANILLAWIDTH / 2);

    attackrange = distance;
    linetarget = NULL;

    // killough 08/02/98: prevent friends from aiming at friends
    aim_flags_mask = mask;

    P_PathTraverse(t1->x, t1->y, x2, y2, (PT_ADDLINES | PT_ADDTHINGS), &PTR_AimTraverse);

    if (linetarget)
        return aimslope;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A few observations without prior familiarity with the DOOM source:

They are using fixed point numbers. Note that fixed point numbers are not built in, so `fixed_t` and associated constants would be defined somewhere in the source. If that doesn’t explain the concept of fixed point, you can read about that elsewhere.

I suspect `FRAC_UNIT` corresponds to 1 in `fixed_t`. So the distance passed to `P_AimLineAttack` is effectively `1024.0`. Then inside `P_AimLineAttack`, the fractional bits of `distance` are thrown away by shifting down by `FRAC_BITS`.

Without digging deeper it’s hard to say why they chose that particular value. As a guess, since I have never heard of DOOM bullets not reaching their target due to distance, it might just be an arbitrary large enough value that allows hitting any visible enemy in any level.

As to why it was expressed as `16 * 64` instead of `1024`, I suspect someone added the `16` quickly, in a way that would be easy to undo, and then left it.

Comment: I understand this 16 * 64 is a considerable distance that covers the entire doom map..